# Morse Theory in Riemannian Geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

In the introduction of Cheeger and Gromoll's paper *On the structure of complete manifolds of nonnegative curvature* the following is stated:

> A point $p \in M$ is called simple if there are no geodesic loops in $M$ closed at $p$. [...] From Morse Theory it is easy to see that the existence of a simple point implies that $M$ is contractible.

For me it is not clear how Morse Theory implies this result.

I read Milnor's book on Morse Theory, but I don't see how the results in it on the topological structure of the path space show how to justify the said implication. So it seems to me that there are other standard applications/constructions/analogies of Morse Theory in Riemannian Geometry.

I'd be glad to get a source on where to read more on morse theoretical applications in Riemannian Geometry and/or a way how to show the above implication with results found in Milnor's *Morse Theory*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $M$ is assumed to be connected and complete (otherwise just puncture your manifold somewhere to remove a geodesic returning to $p$). I think you are looking for theorem 17.3 in Milnor's Morse theory. By the assumptions the homotopy type of $\Omega(M,p,p)$ is a CW complex with one cell (as there is only on geodesic from $p$ to $p$). This means in particular that $\Omega(M,p,p)$ is connected and all higher homotopy groups vanish.

But then, in view of $\pi_k(\Omega(M,p,p))\cong \pi_{k+1}(M)$ all homotopy groups of $M$ vanish as well. Thus $M$ is contractible.

Comment: Why does vanishing homotopy groups imply that $M$ is contractible? For general topological spaces this is not true.

Comment: No, but $\Omega(M,p,p)$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex. It is a famous theorem of Whitehead that if a map $X\rightarrow Y$ of CW complexes induces isomorphisms on the homotopy groups than it is a homotopy equivalence. Now if the homotopy groups of $Y$ are those of a point, the inclusion of a point $X=\{pt\}$ induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups. Hence a space homotopy equivalent to a CW complex with homotopy groups of a point is contractible.

Comment: This indeed uses a lot of theory to make precise. I think the relevant material can be found in Hatcher's Algebraic topology.